# How to test a static method using mock() and spy()

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

the below posted method in the code section contains a static method which is "with()". I want to test the code in below, so I coded the test of this method
as shown in the testing section.

i tried to test the method using both of "spy()" and "mock()" but the test fails alwyas.

please let me know how can I test a method returns void?

**code**

```
 public RequestCreator requestCreatorFromUrl(String picUrl) {
    return Picasso.with(mCtx).load(picUrl);
}
```

**testing**:

```
public class ValidationTest {
@Mock
private Context mCtx = null;
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mCtx = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull("Context is not null", mCtx);
}

 @Test
public void whenRequestCreatorFromUrlTest() throws Exception {
    Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(mCtx);
    Picasso spyPicasso = spy(picasso);
    Uri mockUri = mock(Uri.class);
    RequestCreator requestCreator = Picasso.with(mCtx).load(mockUri);
    RequestCreator spyRequestCreator = spy(requestCreator);

    doReturn(spyRequestCreator).when(spyPicasso.load(mockUri));
    //when(spyPicasso.load(mockUri)).thenReturn(spyRequestCreator);
    RequestCreator actual = spyPicasso.load(mockUri);

    Assert.assertEquals(requestCreator, actual);
}
```

Comment: And of course: the default answer is - if possible change your production code to **not** have that need to mock static methods.

Comment: @GhostCat, Agree, avoid as much as possible the need to mock the static methods. But _Letsamrit_ wrote in comments below, that _because Picasso class is from an external library I am using_. I think in such situation it is a necessary evil to mock the static stuff.

Comment: @mxf Depends on how much effort you are willing to invest. You could *always* create your own *interface* wrapping around such functionality. And then you provide a small impl class that just calls the static stuff. That also helps you in **de coupling** your logic from that external library.

Comment: @GhostCat, thanks, good solution.

Comment: @mxf Sure ;-) ... and most likely, you would find one of my answers ... already saying exactly that somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually, if you end up using `PowerMock`, that’s a good sign that you most possibly are on the wrong way.

What if instead of directly referring to `Picasso`, you create a component, whose responsibility will be to load an image, let's say class `ImageLoader`. What will this give to you?

- Separation of concerns: if tomorrow you decide to move to `Glide`, you shouldn't change each and every class where you were using `Picasso`, you will just change implementation of `ImageLoader`. Other components are non-wiser of these changes, because they are dependent on an abstraction, **not** on implementation
- Seam: this will allow you easily mock dependencies in order to perform unit testing

This will be our abstraction:

```
    interface ImageLoader {
        RequestCreator load(String url);
    }
```

Let’s provide an implementation:

```
    class ImageLoaderImpl implements ImageLoader {
        
        private final Picasso picasso;
    
        public ImageLoaderImpl(Context context) {
            this.picasso = Picasso.with(context);
        }
    
        @Override
        public RequestCreator load(String url) {
            return picasso.load(url);
        }
    }
```

Now, in your components whenever you need `Picasso` use `ImageLoader` instead.

Thus, your method becomes following:

```
    public static RequestCreator requestCreatorFromUrl(String picUrl) {
        return imageLoader.load(picUrl);
    }
```

Then your test will look like this:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        ImageLoaderImpl imageLoader = Mockito.mock(ImageLoaderImpl.class);
        RequestCreator expected = Mockito.mock(RequestCreator.class);
        String TEST_URL = "https://www.some.url/img.jpg";
    
        when(imageLoader.load(TEST_URL)).thenReturn(expexted);
    
        RequestCreator actual = clazzToTest.requestCreatorFromUrl(TEST_URL);
    
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

No mocking of `static` method, no `PowerMock` needed.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Mockito's FAQ](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ):

> **What are the limitations of Mockito**
>
> ...
>
> Cannot mock static methods

Use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/) instead. [Here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method) you will find the detailed instruction about how to mock the static methods.

**Update**

In order to apply the **PowerMock** to your test you need to:

- Add `@PrepareForTest` at test class level:

  `@PrepareForTest(Picasso.class)
  public class ValidationTest {
  ...
  }`
- Call `PowerMockito.mockStatic()` to mock a static class

  `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Picasso.class);`
- Just use `Mockito.when()` to setup your expectation:

  `Mockito.when(Picasso.with(mCtx)).thenReturn(requestCreator);`

The same set of steps is applicable for the `RequestCreator.class`.

P.S. I can make mistakes because I do not know the API of 3rd party library you use.

Comment: One can use **PowerMockito**. Although of course, that means using outdated versions of Mockito.

Comment: can you please provide a hint how to use powermockito to test my method?? because Picasso class is from an external library I am using..i do not have the code of it, i just added the jar to gradle.build

Comment: @GhostCat, I've never heard about the **PowerMockito** framework. Did you mean [org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.4/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html)?

Comment: Yes, but a better link would be: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito

Comment: @mxf i need your help please. i did the following but i have a problem with RequestCreator because Picasso.with(mCtx) returns RequestCreator..how should I test .load method? my code:@Test
    public void whenRequestCreatorFromUrlTest() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Picasso.class);
        Uri mockUri = mock(Uri.class);
        Mockito.when(Picasso.with(mCtx).load(mockUri)).thenReturn(RequestCreator.class)
    }

Comment: @LetsamrIt, split "Mockito.when(Picasso.with(mCtx).load(mockUri)).thenReturn(Re‌​questCreator.class) }" in two separate mock creation - one for `Mockito.when(Picasso.with(mCtx)).then...` and the second one for `Mockito.when(....load(mockUri)).then...`.

Comment: for the 1st split, i do the following and there is error for Picasso.class:
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(Picasso.class);
        Uri mockUri = mock(Uri.class);
        Mockito.when(Picasso.with(mCtx)).thenReturn(Picasso.class);
  
but for the snd split, i receive always errors..i would appreciate it if you help me

Answer (score 0):

Forget PowerMockito. With mockito-inline version > 4.2.0 you can use it by `@Mock` annotation. I haven't test your code, but you can have some insights with this answer.

You can check the use in my conclusion work of university ([Github](https://github.com/orion-services/activity/blob/5565518a058ae482f05c3597f8ccfb56525b193d/src/test/java/dev/orion/api/UserEndpointTest.java#L51)).

```java
class Test {
    @Mock
    MockedStatic<Picasso> picasso;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
       doNothing().when(Picasso..with(any()));
    }
}
```

There's another approach that consist to mock static manually, which I don't prefer, but work fine. You can find the example in [Baeldung website](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods)

Answer (score 0):

```java
try (MockedStatic<SOMECLASS> instantMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SOMECLASS.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
            instantMockedStatic.when(SOME_CLASS::SOME_STATIC_METHOD).thenReturn(startValue);
   // some validation logic here, including methods that call real class...
}
```

e.g.

```java
final Instant startValue = Instant.ofEpochSecond(0);
try (MockedStatic<Instant> instantMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Instant.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
    instantMockedStatic.when(Instant::now).thenReturn(startValue);

    Assertions.assertEquals(startValue.plus(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) , somethingThatUsesInstantNowAndAdds1Sec());
```